# Correct way to describe your academic degree

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Earlier when I wanted to say that I have done my three year degree course from a university I generally used to say that "I have done my **graduation** in History from ABC University".

**Graduation** was the word that I used to use for that three year period of my study. But today I found out that native English speakers don't use the word graduation in that sense. I checked various dictionaries and now I understand when to use that word.

But now I am confused as to how to refer to that three year period of study.

I have thought of a few ways by which could tell someone about my degree, but I would really like to know what native English speakers think of these sentences.

Also, please mention any other ways of saying that.

1. I did/have done my bachelor's in History from ABC University.
2. I did/have done my bachelor's degree in History from ABC University.
3. I did/have done BA in History from ABC University.
4. I have completed/finished my bachelor's in History from ABC University.
5. I have completed/finished BA in History from ABC University.

Please suggest other sentences as well.

Comment: We don't normally say *I have done my graduation in X.* It's usually just *I **graduated** in X.*

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I found that out today. But how would I say that I have studied this course from this university? I have heard people say "I did my A levels from St.Mary". Likewise, can I say "I did/completed my BA from ABC University" or "I did/completed bachelor's from ABC University"?

Comment: *"I am confused as to how to refer to that three year period of study."* If that was your first degree, '**my undergraduate days**'.

Comment: Numbers 3 and 5 require either a possessive (my) or indefinite article (a) before **BA**.  Otherwise these are all fine in American English, though other parts of the world may find them less idiomatic. I might sometimes say, "I did my **undergrad** in History at ABC University," which implies that I have subsequent postgraduate degree.

Comment: Thanks @Weather Vane for responding. I am about to enroll in a MA degree program in a different university. What if someone asked me where I did my BA from, how would I respond to that? Earlier I would have said "I did my graduation from ABC University". But now I know that's wrong. So would I now instead of graduation say "I did my BA or bachelor's from ABC University?"

Comment: You graduated in history at ABC University. Please see ELU question [Did I “get” (or “take”) my degree “from” (or “in”) the University of Somewhere?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49722/did-i-get-or-take-my-degree-from-or-in-the-university-of-somewhere)

Comment: @Weather Vane What if I wanted to phrase it like "do or complete"? Like people say "I did my A levels from St.Mary's". Can I say "I did my BA or bachelor's or bachelor's degree from ABC University"?

Comment: Thanks @Canadian Yankee for responding. So it is perfectly natural to say "I have done my bachelor's degree from ABC University"? Also, you mentioned that people in some parts of the world may find it less idiomatic. What would you say would be a more idiomatic or natural way of saying this?

Comment: Thanks very much @Weather Vane for the link. Is it not very normal for people to say "I have done my BA or bachelor's degree from ABC University". Now I know people usually say "graduated from", but what if someone asked them "where did you study your BA course?

Comment: You say "I was at XYZ [University]".

Comment: What if you had to also mention the name of your degree like BA History or bachelor's degree,etc. Then how would you phrase that?

Comment: I got a BA in history at XYZ. In a job application: I was awarded a BA in history at XYZ.

Comment: I understand I am being too irritating. But the thing is I used to use phrase "I did/have done my graduation from ABC University". Since I found out that the word graduation is not used in that way, I want to keep the same sentence structure but replace the word "graduation with something else. That's why I keep asking you to phrase it using the word "I did or I have completed...from ABC University".

Comment: Actually, it is a bit more natural to day, "I have done my bachelor's degree **at** ABC University" (not "from").  You could also say, "I **got** my bachelor's degree **from** ABC University." The verb/preposition pairs would be "do...at" and "get...from".  As for what might be more idiomatic in other parts of the world, I'm not a good person to ask because I'm most comfortable with American (and Canadian) English.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee Thank you so much. This was very very helpful. The "do...at" and "get... from" pairs really cleared up a big doubt. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I did a BA (in History) at York University.

You can't compare "graduation" (a ceremony where you receive your degree) with "A-levels" (a two year course).  The name of the course is a "BA" and that is what you "did". If the subject was History then "BA in History".  Alternatives to "BA" are "BSc" (etc as appropriate), or "Bachelor's (degree)" or "First degree".

Beware of forgetting that there are two people in any conversation:

It is normal and natural not to try and give all the information that you have in one sentence, but instead allow for the natural to and fro of a converstation.

> Where were you before?  (in context = "which university were you at before")
>
> I went to York.  (implictly York University)
>
> Oh right, what did you do there? American Studies?  (makes a guess based on some context from outside this conversation)
>
> No, straight History,  I specialised in American History in my final year though.
>
> Which periods?
>
> Mostly 1800s, you know, Civil War, and all that.

You see a conversation develops... You don't need to work out how to say all that in one go!

Comment: Thanks so much James K for explaining in such great detail. The thing is, in India a lot of people use the phrase "I completed my graduation from ABC University". Now I have to write a short introduction about myself for a new course that I have just got into. A lot of other students used that phrase - "I have completed my graduation from". But when I found out that it is not the correct usage I was in a bit of a fix. Now how would you introduce yourself there on that space? Would you say "I have completed my BA in History at York University"? Or does it sound unnatural to you?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention I have to mention History Honours not just History.

Comment: Please try to include all relevant information in the question not in comments.  "I have to **write** a short introduction is quite different from "what if someone asks me..."  We can't read your mind.  If you are asking about writing that makes the question different.

Comment: Now.  Please read the answer I wrote.  I said the form of words to use "I did a BA in History at York University".  There may be other expressions that are also acceptable, but repeatly asking "what about ...." will get you nowhere.  Moreover if you want to write in the Indian dialect then please ask Indian dialect speakers.  The point of asking here is surely to get the advice of English and American native speakers. Perhaps the Indian dialect speakers say something else. I'm not going to tell people how to speak like an Indian dialect speaker (because I'm not one)